# System.Drawing.FontFamily does not accept Uri-based Font

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

Is there a way to define an external font as a new `System.Drawing.FontFamily`? I tried using this code:

```
 FontFamily robotoLight = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), 
                                         "./Fonts/#Roboto Light");
```

And shows this error:

> Cannot convert from `System.Uri` to `string`

I realized that I've been using a different reference and the one that accepts `Uri` is the `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily`, so it does not work.

I researched and saw that to define custom fonts is to use the `PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile`, but it's using an absolute path for the font, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473139/new-system-drawing-font-code-behind).

My fonts currently resides in a `fonts` folder inside the project, and is built to be included in the `.exe` file, so an absolute path is no-go for me.

And I need to use `System.Drawing` and not `System.Windows.Media` because I'm creating a customized `MessageBox`

Comment: Are you sure that "Roboto Light" is the name of the font and not just the name of the file? Try "./Fonts/#Roboto".

Comment: @mm8 I'm sure. I've been using it on other parts of the project. And I checked it by using the installer of the font

Comment: Oh, a System.Drawing.FontFamily doesn't understand pack URIs.

Comment: @mm8 Yeah, and I can't use `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily` because I need `System.Drawing.FontFamily`

Comment: @Downvoter Mind explaining?

Comment: Did you read this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556147/how-to-quickly-and-easily-embed-fonts-in-winforms-app-in-c-sharp

Comment: @mm8 Nope, I didn't found that question, maybe because I'm using "WPF" as a search query

Comment: System.Drawing.FontFamily is not WPF :)

Comment: @mm8 Oh, ok then. Guess I was right then, because I have just copied a class that creates a custom message box, and it's using `className : Forms`. Nevertheless, I didn't found that question and I still need to use `System.Drawing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Drawing.FontFamily` doesn't understand pack URIs. Please refer to the following question for an example of how you could use an embedded font with the `System.Drawing.FontFamily` class:

[How to quickly and easily embed fonts in winforms app in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556147/how-to-quickly-and-easily-embed-fonts-in-winforms-app-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Implemented it, but not sure if it really works. I compared it to another with a gibberish font name to revert it to the default font, and it seems different I tried using a `BoldItalic` version, but it does not accept either `FontStyle.Regular` nor `FontStyle.Bold`. Anyway, thanks for the link.